# Instance of Forward declared Class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

It's  the follow up question of this: [error C2504 circular inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203081/error-c2504-circular-inclusion).
Child if forward declared in parent's header.

It is not included, so the complier wont find Child? Then how do i instantiate a new Child object from Parent object.

**Parent.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
class Child;
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent();
    void GiveBirth();
    ~Parent();
    vector<Child*> children;
};
```

**Parent.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Parent.h"


Parent::Parent()
{

}

void Parent::GiveBirth()
{
    Child ch = Child(); //Error: incomplete type is not allowed
}

Parent::~Parent()
{
}
```

**Child.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Parent.h"
class Child : Parent
{
public:
    Child();
    ~Child();
};
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Child.h"


Child::Child()
{
}


Child::~Child()
{
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but I think the answer is that `Parent.cpp` should `#include "Child.h"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some reading list for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29

**Parent.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"


Parent::Parent()
{

}

void Parent::GiveBirth()
{
    //Child ch = Child(); //Error: incomplete type is not allowed
    children.push_back(new Child());
}

Parent::~Parent()
{
}
```

Comment: Using `new` does not remove the need for `Child` being completely defined there. Adding an explanation why you use `new` there might be indicated.

Comment: if i try to call GiveBirth from the constructor, the programm freezes.

Comment: Surely it will cause infinite loop. Parent::Parent() -> Parent::GiveBirth() -> Child::Child() -> Parent::Parent() -> ...